# Binding string to a textbox based on which button is clicked

Tags: c#, .net, wpf

I have an editor (textbox) and I'd like to bind different texts to it based on which button is clicked.

I could use a command on the button and pass the string which I'd like to edit through commandparameter and update the string which is bound to the textbox. This will work but it's not going to save the modifications because there is no binding between the text (which was passed through the commandparameter) and the textbox's text.

My question is, how should I implement this bind neatly without accessing the textbox directly from the View Model?

edit: it's probably vague what I'm trying to achieve. I try to clarify it a bit:

So let's say I have several different buttons, if I click one of those, it should bind some string to the editor's textbox, where I can modify it and save it later.

```
     <Button Content="Edit query" Command="{Binding ShowQueryInEditorCommand}" CommandParameter="{Binding SomeSqlStringToBeEdited}"/>

     <Button Content="Edit query" Command="{Binding ShowQueryInEditorCommand}" CommandParameter="{Binding SomeOtherSqlStringToBeEdited}"/>
```

This is what the command will execute:

```
    public void ShowQueryInEditor(object o)
    {            
        string SqlStatementParam = o as string;
        if (SqlStatementParam != null)
            SQLStatement = SqlStatementParam;            
    }
```

And the editor TextBox itself:

```
    <TextBox Text="{Binding SQLStatement}">
```

As you can see, this is very rudimentary as it just sets the SQLStatement string, but there is no bind between them so it cannot reflect the modifications back to SomeSqlStringToBeEdited/SomeOtherSqlStringToBeEdited. This is what I would like to achieve, to bind that string somehow to the textbox when the button is clicked.

Comment: Can you post at least the code of one butto and the textbox? Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to

> but the problem is that the buttons are created dynamically

1) Wrap you query text and button into view model like this:

```
public class ViewModel : ViewModelBase
{
    public ViewModel()
    {
        this.turnIsSelectedOnCommand = new RelayCommand(() => IsSelected = true);
    }

    public String Text
    {
        get { return text; }
        set
        {
            if (text != value)
            {
                text = value;
                OnPropertyChanged("Text");
            }
        }
    }
    private String text;

    public Boolean IsSelected
    {
        get { return isSelected; }
        set
        {
            if (isSelected != value)
            {
                isSelected = value;
                OnPropertyChanged("IsSelected");
            }
        }
    }
    private Boolean isSelected;

    public RelayCommand TurnIsSelectedOnCommand
    {
        get { return turnIsSelectedOnCommand; }
    }
    private readonly RelayCommand turnIsSelectedOnCommand;
}
```

2) Put your dynamically created text/buttons into collection. For simplicity, I've added them to array:

```
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        DataContext = new[] 
        { 
            new ViewModel { Text = "SELECT * FROM Foo", IsSelected = true },
            new ViewModel { Text = "SELECT * FROM Bar" },
            new ViewModel { Text = "DROP TABLE Foo" },
            new ViewModel { Text = "DROP TABLE Bar" },
        };
    }
```

3) Bind the collection with ListBox, and the editor - with the `Text` of the selected item:

```
<ListBox Grid.Row="0" Margin="5" ItemsSource="{Binding}" x:Name="lbItems">
    <ListBox.ItemsPanel>
        <ItemsPanelTemplate>
            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal"
                        VerticalAlignment="Center"
                        HorizontalAlignment="Right"/>
        </ItemsPanelTemplate>
    </ListBox.ItemsPanel>
    <ListBox.ItemContainerStyle>
        <Style TargetType="{x:Type ListBoxItem}">
            <Setter Property="IsSelected" Value="{Binding IsSelected}"/>
            <Style.Resources>
                <SolidColorBrush x:Key="{x:Static SystemColors.HighlightBrushKey}"
                                 Color="Transparent"/>
            </Style.Resources>
        </Style>
    </ListBox.ItemContainerStyle>
    <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <Button Content="Edit query" Command="{Binding TurnIsSelectedOnCommand}"/>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
</ListBox>

<TextBox Grid.Row="1" Margin="5" Text="{Binding Path=SelectedItem.Text, ElementName=lbItems}" />
```

I've added some style modifications.
First modifies buttons layout.
Second means, that when you will push the button and ViewModel will become selected, list box item will be selected too.
Third hides selection from the background of the selected item.

Hope, this helps.

Comment: Thank you Dennis, by the looks of it, this is a very nice and neat solution. I managed to solve the problem differently, perhaps not as nicely as you did, but works well in my particular case. Since this might be useful for others with a similar problem I'll mark your complete solution as an answer. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

There are two basic ways I can think of: through code, or through Xaml.

In code, instead of accessing the textbox from the ViewModel, add a new property to the ViewModel for the "DisplayText" or "SelectedText", or whatever makes sense in your scenario.  Bind your textbox to that property instead, and then put the rest of the logic you need inside the setter (or, if it's a `DependencyProperty`, the `OnPropertyChanged` callback).  That keeps all the logic in your ViewModel and means the Xaml doesn't have to care.

Or in Xaml, you could use triggers and templates to change the textbox depending on the selected button.  Most likely form your description, I would suggest having *multiple* textboxes, one bound to each string, and switch the visible textbox based on the button that's clicked.  This keeps your ViewModel ignorant of this display-specific logic, and allows you to change it more easily later on.

Personally, I would likely suggest the Xaml approach, but it will depend on your specific situation.

Comment: I like the idea of your Xaml approach, but the problem is that the buttons are created dynamically, I can't think of a way to solve this with triggers, any suggestion?

Comment: Regarding the code behind solution, the SQLStatement is the "DisplayText" or "SelectedText" what you described. What I don't know is the logic that binds the SomeSqlStringToBeEdited to the SQLStatement. Could you please revise my code above? I'm probably missing something very simple but I can't figure out what it is.